# Attach RadToolTip to GridHyperLinkColumn based on some condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, tooltip

Is there a way to conditionally attach a RadToolTip to a GridHyperLinkColumn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tooltip/examples/targetcontrolsandajax/defaultcs.aspx) and set the tooltip conditionally instead for each row cell.